# Reading from a file how to append strings to a list until a specific marker in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a input text file:

```
  This file contains information of students who are joining picnic:
     @@@ bob alice rhea john 
     mary alex roma
     peter &##&
```

Now I would like to append students name in a list  in a line when find @@@ marker & stop appending when find &##& marker. Output should be(using python):

```
bob alice rhea john mary alex roma peter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
txt = """This file contains information of students who are joining picnic:
     @@@ bob alice rhea john 
     mary alex roma
     peter &##&"""
```

or :

```
txt = open("./file.txt").read()  

ls = txt.split("@@@")[1].split("&##&")[0].split()
print(ls)
```

This prints :

```
['bob', 'alice', 'rhea', 'john', 'mary', 'alex', 'roma', 'peter']
```

Comment: What if I would like to print the start marker as well. Could you answer please? TIA.

Comment: Write which part you mean ?

Comment: Output should be: @@@ bob alice rhea john mary alex roma peter

Comment: Change it to this : `ls = txt.split(":")[1].split("&##&")[0].split()`

Comment: It's not working. I have some strings before the marker as well.

Comment: Possibly characters `:` There are in the string I think you add the characters you want manually

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall` with `re.sub`:

```py
inp = """This file contains information of students who are joining picnic:
@@@ bob alice rhea john 
mary alex roma
peter &##&"""

output = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.findall(r'@@@\s+(.*?)\s+&##&', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])
print(output)  # bob alice rhea john mary alex roma peter
```

If you want a list, then use:

```
output = re.split(r'\s+', re.findall(r'@@@\s+(.*?)\s+&##&', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['bob', 'alice', 'rhea', 'john', 'mary', 'alex', 'roma', 'peter']
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but having below error for my actual file reading from text file.   "File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: The code I have pasted above works verbatim as stated.  You must be doing something wrong in your script.